# How to monitor for file appearance and move it to current working directory?

Tags: autohotkey

I'm trying to :

1. Capture a screenshot (using FastStone Screen Capture); the result is an image saved to `C:\Capture\screenshot.jpg`.
2. Monitor `C:\Capture` and if `screenshot.jpg` is found, move it to the current working directory (the active Explorer window).

So if I capture `screenshot.jpg` while in `C:\Pictures`, the file should be automatically moved from `C:\Capture` to `C:\Pictures`. In other words the image captured should be moved to the directory it's a screenshot of (the active Explorer window).

FastStone Screen Capture can save the image to a variable path. But I have not found such a variable for a currently open directory.

https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/Q1rtTdMOKYq6SXXyElpy0QIbAg5hDqT8BIPW7Rc2tA=w427-h207-p-no

Comment: What's the point in taking screenshots of an explorer window?

Comment: say you have directories containing albums, or projects.  what i like to do is take a small screenshot of relevant content (a thumbnail) and place it inside the directory called folder.jpg

 - - tried to embed an image ion the first post to show an example

this makes it easy to see and identify.

Answer (score 3):

A few hints on how to achieve your goals:

1. You can use AHK libraries to take screenshots (e.g. [Gdip.ahk](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/91585-screen-capture-using-only-ahk-no-3rd-party-software-required/)). You can fully control them (image formats, crop/cut screen areas) and most importantly, you can choose the output path.
2. On Windows 7, I usually use this code snippet to get the active explorer path:

`if( WinActive("ahk_class CabinetWClass") ) {
    ControlGetText, wDir, ToolbarWindow322
    RegExMatch(wDir, ":\s*(.*)", wDir)
    wDir := wDir1 ; Current path will be stored in wDir
}`

The procedure would be straightforward: Define a hotkey that starts the procedure. Retrieve the current explorer path. Take a (partial) screenshot and save it in the path you just retrieved.

Answer (score 0):

Another tip on how to achieve this:

Use Autoit library

```
#include <ScreenCapture.au3>

; Capture full screen
_ScreenCapture_Capture(@MyDocumentsDir & "\GDIPlus_Image1.jpg")

; Capture region
_ScreenCapture_Capture(@MyDocumentsDir & "\GDIPlus_Image2.jpg", 0, 0, 796, 596)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a very useful library that I use located [here](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/60985-get-paths-of-selected-items-in-an-explorer-window/), which lets you easily grab the path of the current Explorer window. You could use it like this.

```
#Include Explorer.ahk
; Can change this to the hotkey for your screenshot app 
; or have the script send the key on first line
+PrintScreen:: 
    SSFile := "C:\Capture\screenshot.jpg"
    CurrentDir := Explorer_GetPath()

    While ! FileExist(SSFile)
        Sleep, 500

    FileCopy, %SSFile%, %CurrentDir%
    FileDelete, %SSFile%
Return
```

I have not built in a timeout for looking for the file at this point in time, but that might be something you need eventually.